# VPN connection drops after ~23 minutes

Tags: vpn

I have set up VPN server (PPTP) on Windows Server 2012, I connect as a client from a Windows 7 PC and after roughly 23 minutes the connection drops, redials and connects fine.

- There are no connection limits on the server side.
- I have tried with dynamic dns and directly with the public IP, the result is the same.
- I login to the VPN with local account.
- Windows firewall is disabled on client side, Kaspersky Internet Security is installed
- Connection also drops from other PC's in the same network, though I have not tested connecting from another place that uses different router (maybe its the router)

Comment: You might have better luck asking on Serverfault

Answer (score 0):

Seems a SA Lifetime issue, look in your events for Event 542 , Event 543  as per https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc302672.aspx

Comment: I've looked for these events but found none. If I use no authentication would it solve the problem?

Comment: I set the authorization on Unencrypted Password (PAP), and the connection is not dropping now but I cant acces any shares because the clients on the server are unauthentocated.

Comment: It appears to be problem with the NAP, I have created custom policy for not NAP capable devices and there is a MS-Quarantine-Session-Timeout attribute which was set to 20min.